# Using OpenCV 2.0.0a with dev c++

Tags: c++, opencv, dev-c++

OpenCV 2.0.0a is very different to the older version of OpenCV and so is very different to setup. I have tried to set it up for Visual C++ Express 2008 but to no avail so I wanted to ask whether anyone has got it to work on Dev C++ and if yes can they tell me how.

Comment: Why is this question tagged **C++Builder** shouldn't it be tagged **dev-c++** instead?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/DevCpp)